# http status: 403, code:-1 - https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/: User not registered in the Developer Dashboard

Tags: spotipy

After testing the Flask example on spotipy/app.py.

I noticed after adding my own email, I keep getting User not registered in the Developer Dashboard.

Why could this be the issue? I am using the exact spotify account when I authenticate

Comment: Are you registered in the Developer Dashboard?

Comment: Yes, I registered my exact email in the Developer Dashboard 'User and Access'

Comment: You don't have to add your own email if that's the same email of your development account.

Comment: Hmm ok, it still doesn't work tho.. not sure why.